Calculating the shift of the ground state energy from Lippmann-Schwingers $T$ operator
If we consider a Hamiltonian $H = H_0 + V$, where $V$ is some perturbation,
the Lippmann-Schwinger equation in operator form is given by
$$T_E = V + V\frac{1}{E-H_0}T_E.$$
Now lets assume the free system has an energy spectrum which is bounded from below, so
there exists a unique ground state $|0\rangle$ with energy $E_0|0\rangle = H_0|0\rangle$. I am interested in the energy of the interacting ground state.
From time independent perturbation theory we know that the shift of the ground state energy $\Delta E$ can be written as
$$\Delta E = \langle0|V\sum_{n=0}^\infty\big(\frac{1}{E_0-H_0}V\big)^n|0\rangle,$$
(See "Fetter&Walecka - Quantum Theory of many particle systems", equations (9.48) and (9.49)). Now to me it seems like the summand in this equation resembles the Lippmann-Schwinger equation if we iteratively insert it into itself and set $E=E_0$. Then the shift of the ground state energy could be written as
$$\Delta E =\langle0| T_{E_0} |0\rangle. $$
This expression seems very simple to me, but I haven't seen it anywhere in the literature. Is my derivation correct? Also can I use the same argument to calculate the energy shifts of all levels (asuming they are non-degenerate)?

Isn't $T(z)=VG(z)(z-H_0)$, and thus $T(E_0)=0$?

Note that F&W actually write the connected expectation value in Eq. (9.48), which is a rather different thing. The PT formula as you write it is not correct; just compare its result in third order with the usual RSPT result. On the other hand, Brillouin-Wigner PT looks just like this, but with the exact energy in the resolvent (not the zeroth-order one). This could be the connection with the Lippmann-Schwinger equation that you are looking for.

re my first comment: probably as long as $E_0$ is not an eigenvalue of $H$ or so... but I haven't thought about it too much...anyway, are you sure you don't miss some projector in your expression (expansion) for $\delta E$?

@dennismoore94 You are correct about the expectation value in F&W being connected, but I don't understand the meaning of this in quantum mechanics. Considering a single particle system and a perturbation which is just a potential, I would expect the potential to scatter single particle states to single particle states. I dont see how this could generate "disconnected diagrams".

The label "connected" just refers to formal manipulations. My point is simply that you cannot write RSPT as a geometric series. Just compare your $n=2$ term (which would correspond to $E^{(3)}$) with the known formula of third-order energy. In the correct formula, there are two terms (both of them represented by a connected diagram in the single-particle case, respectively), but you only get one of them. In Brillouin-Wigner PT, you actually get the energy as a geometric series (with the exact $E$ in the denominator), so, if anything, that is the one that could be related to Lippmann-Schwinger.
